# Python3 Selenium: Wait for a Page Load in New Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I've looked all over and found some very nice solutions to wait for page load and window load (and yes I know there are a lot of Stack questions regarding them in isolation). However, there doesn't seem to be a way to combine these two waits effectively.

Taking my primary inspiration from the end of [this post](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html), I came up with these two functions to be used in a "with" statement:

```
#This is within a class where the browser is at self.driver

@contextmanager
def waitForLoad(self, timeout=60):
    oldPage = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    yield
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(staleness_of(oldPage))

@contextmanager
def waitForWindow(self, timeout=60):
    oldHandles = self.driver.window_handles
    yield
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
        lambda driver: len(oldHandles) != len(self.driver.window_handles)
    )

#example
button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
if button:
    with self.waitForPage():
        button.click()
```

These work great in isolation. However, they can't be combined due to the way each one checks their own internal conditions. For example, this code will fail to wait until the second page has loaded because the act of switching windows causes "oldPage" to become stale:

```
@contextmanager
def waitForWindow(self, timeout=60):
    with self.waitForLoad(timeout):
        oldHandles = self.driver.window_handles
        yield
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
            lambda driver: len(oldHandles) != len(self.driver.window_handles)
        )
        self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Is there some Selenium method that will allow these to work together?

Comment: Might be off because I have never used Selenium but why don't you just use a callback system? Have you tried this? Or you could (if there is a method in Selenium to check if it is currently waiting for a page or window to load, if so then recall the function? Update me if this is possible!

Comment: This is park of a web scraper that acts like a human. The command is "click an arbitrary element that can be clicked". It doesn't have access to the callbacks, as far as I'm aware. The "WebDriverWait" class is what Selenium uses to block until conditions are met.

Comment: You can create your own callbacks? Develop a self maintaining loop thread independent of anything else. Add some code for registering callbacks when OnWindowWaitStart, OnWindowWaitEnd, OnLoadStart, OnLoadEnd. Thread can monitor when each is executed. If one is executed while another then re exec!